# Google geolocalização funciona no browser do pc, mas não no browser do android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-chrome, geolocalização

Usando Ruby, Sinatra, Slim, Javascript, Google maps v3 API.
A Geolocalização funciona perfeitamente no browser no PC, o mapa é gerado com o marcador do parceiro, quando se clica no botão é solicitado a geolocalização ao browser, cria um novo marcador nessa posição e gera a rota.
Porem no browser no android quando clica no botão cai no erro:

```
infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
'Erro: O serviço de geolocalização falhou.'
```

Na minha API KEY ativei tudo o que era relacionado ao MAPS e ANDROID.

Fiz um Fiddle, e nele funciona no android, só que está sem API KEY.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aogr4u8o/3/)

EDIT 1:
  Descobri que o google só permite usar o getCurrentPosition() em conexões HTTPS:// (nunca iria funcionar acessando pelo meu IP local), no heroku só funciona se eu usar o https:// antes do endereço tanto no browser do PC quanto no browser do android.

```
<button id="rota">Rota até o parceiro.</button>
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
  var map;
  var pos;

  // Pega o click no botão
  document.getElementById("rota").onclick = function() {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // solicita ao browser a localização
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Você está aqui.');
        map.setCenter(pos);

        // Gera a rota
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Erro: O serviço de geolocalização falhou.' :
                          'Erro: O seu navegador não suporta geolocalização.');
  }

  // Primeira função chamada quando o mapa é gerado
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {lat: -3.7913486, lng: -38.589312}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  }

  // Cria o marcador para o endereco do parceiro
  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = 'Fortaleza - CE';
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  // Função que gera rota
  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: pos,
      destination: 'Fortaleza - CE',
      // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
      // using square brackets and a string value as its
      // "property."
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode['DRIVING']
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
  * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O google só permite usar o getCurrentPosition() em conexões HTTPS:// (nunca iria funcionar acessando pelo meu IP local), no heroku só funciona se eu usar o https:// antes do endereço tanto no browser do PC quanto no browser do android.

Referência: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: Se esta é a solução, marque a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Não posso, a resposta foi eu mesmo que dei. Só posso marcar como correta depois de dois dias.